# Extend str class to take additional parameters

Tags: python, string, class, extend

I want to create a new class that is a special type of string.  I want it to inherit all the methods of the str class, but I want to be able to pass it an additional parameter that it can use.  Something like this:

```
class URIString(str, ns = namespace): # ns defaults to global variable namespace
    def getLocalName(self):
        return self[(self.find(ns)+len(ns)):] # self should still act like a string
        # return everything in the string after the namespace
```

I know the syntax isn't right.  But hopefully it conveys the idea that I'm trying to get at.

Comment: You should use a tutorial to learn how to do inheritance. Stackoverflow is not here to handhold people.

Comment: @Marcin: In his defense, it isn't obvious how to inherit from str....

Comment: @Marcin: do you just troll newbie questions on Stackoverflow all day or what?

Comment: @Marcin - hey, three years on now and I'm a way better programmer, thanks to all the nice people who helped out, and no thanks to your worthless comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would want to do something like this:

```
class URIString(str):
    _default_namespace = "default"

    def __init__(self, value, namespace=_default_namespace):
        self.namespace = namespace

    def __new__(cls, value, namespace=_default_namespace):
        return super().__new__(cls, value)      

    @property
    def local_name(self):
        return self[(self.find(self.namespace)+len(self.namespace)):]
```

I have used the `@property` decorator to turn `getLocalName()` into the attribute `local_name` - in python, getters/setters are considered bad practice.

Note that pre-Python 3.x, you need to use `super(URIString, cls).__new__(cls, value)`.

Comment: Did you even try this code? There are at least three problems with it.

Comment: @NedBatchelder I hit submit by accident while I was still compiling my answer, I'll update it after testing.

Comment: There we go, fixed. When I first submitted, it was just off the top of my head, so excuse the initial inaccuracy.

Comment: @Lattyware: Don't worry, just FYI *(since one time I had the same problem)* you can click to delete your answer, edit and then undelete :)

Comment: @RikPoggi Cheers, I'll do that next time, or maybe I'll just start drafting my answers in a text editor to be safe.

Comment: The first parameter to `__new__()` is the class, not the instance. You *return* the instance. So you need to call `super().__new__()` *first* and then set the attribute on its return value before returning it. Otherwise you're setting the `namespace` attribute on the class.

Comment: @kindall Ugh, this is what happens when I start correcting in a rush, making all kinds of stupid mistakes, thanks for pointing it out. Corrected. Hoping there are no more.